# React: Keep scroll at current element when data update like messenger(facebook)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm creating an chatbox using Reactjs.

Like messenger of facebook, when I scroll to top of list chat, it will load older message.

The problem is it scroll to top when state updated.

I want to keep current interface (keep positions of message I see before load) and does not scroll to top.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can I see your code ,please?

Comment: The implementation of this is usually very irritating but there's no need to reinvent the wheel. Try using https://github.com/vytenisu/use-chat-scroll